# Change text color to an specific character using angular and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to change the text color of a row in an HTML table using jQuery if it founds this characther **"-"**. The data is coming from a webservice and I'm using AngularJS but I don't know if I have to use directive to do this.

This is my angular expression:

`<td>{{example.name}}</td>`

and this is what I tried:

```
  $('.example.name').each(function() {
    if($(this).contains(-)) {
       $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
```

I put this code inside the controller that is bringing the data but it's not working, that's when I thought in directives.

So how can I achive this

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `"` around `-` making it an operator and a Syntax Error. Change it to:

```
if ($(this).contains("-")) {
//-------------------^-^
```

The only place you can use without `"` is:

```
if ($(".some-class p:contains(-)")) {
```

Sorry I am not sure about the angular way! `:(`

Comment: Don't worry, everything helps.

Thanks for your time ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ng-class`/`ng-style` directive to implement the same thing in angular way. `ng-class` is the preferable way to it.

**HTML**

```
<td ng-class="{red: doHighlight(exmaple.name)}" >
  ...content...
</td>
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.doHighlight = function(name){
   return name.contains('-');
}
```

Comment: Using the templating engine is probably the way to go.

Comment: I was just saying your answer is probably better than mine. Using Angular instead of jQuery. Keeping styling and layout in the template just seems cleaner.

Comment: @YourFriendKen yes..make use of inbuilt directive rather than going for jQuery

Comment: Thank's to both @YourFriendKen

I was hoping to do this the "angular" way

Comment: @PankajParkar 

Me again, I was trying something like this: ng-style="{$('p:contains('-')').css('color','red')}" but not getting any result and I don't understand why.

Also the solution you gave only works for example.name expression right? If I want to evaluate for any row in the table should be something like Ken said $("td:contains(-)").css("color","red"); no?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to mix jQuery while dealing with angular?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td:contains(-)").css("color","red");
```

Did you try using the jQuery selector `:contains()`?

https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

You may also want to add a class to the `<td>` elements that you want to query.

```
<td class="example-name">{{example.name}}</td>
```

Then change the query:

```
$("td.example-name:contains(-)").css("color","red");
```

Comment: This will work, now I think this should go inside a directive right?

Because if I put that line inside between a <script> tag is not working..